# The IAsyncResult asynchronous pattern - TAP and REST API

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, asynchronous

I have a question regarding the following API / Class for wcf.(http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html)

It exposes The IAsyncResult asynchronous pattern based on task-based asynchronous pattern.Is it a correct approach?
What is a callback?
What is REST API?(Task based one?)

```
[DataContract]
public class CalculatorFault
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Message { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ICalculator
{
  // Synchronous equivalent:
  //  [OperationContract]
  //  [FaultContract(typeof(CalculatorFault))]
  //  uint Divide(uint numerator, uint denominator);

  [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
  [FaultContract(typeof(CalculatorFault))]
  IAsyncResult BeginDivide(uint numerator, uint denominator, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
  uint EndDivide(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
}
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
  public async Task<uint> DivideAsync(uint numerator, uint denominator)
  {
    try
    {
      var myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => numerator / denominator);
      var result = await myTask;
      return result;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException)
    {
      throw new FaultException<CalculatorFault>(new CalculatorFault { Message = "Undefined result" });
    }
  }
public IAsyncResult BeginDivide(uint numerator, uint denominator, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
  {
    // See the Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern document for an explanation of the Begin/End implementations.
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<uint>(state);
    var task = DivideAsync(numerator, denominator);
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
      if (t.IsFaulted)
        tcs.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
      else if (t.IsCanceled)
        tcs.TrySetCanceled();
      else
        tcs.TrySetResult(t.Result);

      if (callback != null)
        callback(tcs.Task);
    });

    return tcs.Task;
  }

  public uint EndDivide(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
  {
    try
    {
      return ((Task<uint>)asyncResult).Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
      // Note: the original stack trace is lost by this re-throw, but it doesn't really matter.
      throw ex.InnerException;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It its by [stephen-cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) I would bet it's right.

Comment: @Harrison - I see.It just looks a bit strange to use Task for IAsyncResult.I want to understand the logic on which it is based and why he uses such approach.As well what is a call back here?And REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a correct approach?

Yes, but it's not necessary anymore. The "today" in that blog post refers to .NET 4.0, which was current when the blog post was written (August 2012). The "tomorrow" in that blog post refers to .NET 4.5.

In modern (.NET 4.5) WCF servers, you can just use the task-based API and ignore the old `IAsyncResult` compatibility translations.

> What is a callback?

A method that is invoked when something happens.

> What is REST API?

Representational state transfer, a fancy term that essentially means you use the HTTP protocol the way it was originally designed to be used. WebAPI is a modern REST-friendly framework that supports ASP.NET and self-hosting.